# Water stains on the carpets near the edges?

Tags: water, flooring

I have these water stains on my carpet near the linings of the doors and the stairs. They appeared some months ago. I haven't stayed in this house for long.

The green carpet you see is the corridor, bit on the right of that is also little bit noticeable (part of staircase) and there is some discoloration and a bit wet on the upper of the picture near the doorway (which is the living room).

On the left is the kitchen it has a vinyl sheet flooring and according to moisture readings it is dry.

Any ideas what could have caused that? I haven't spilled anything, nor is any pipe leaking and the roof is not leaking.

For context the house is in North West England, not too far from Scotland. It is an 100 years old house. It has two floors and it's a terraced house. The phenomenon of what you see happened on the ground floor.

[image]

Comment: Any signs in the other rooms at the doorways shown?

Comment: It is more prevelant there. The green carpet you see is the corridor, bit on the right of that is also little bit noticeable (part of staircase) and there is some discoloration and a bit wet on the upper of the picture near the doorway (which is the living room). Hence, I would say mostly or only there.

Comment: Do you have a concrete slab beneath the carpet and/or whatever the floor type is on the left?

Comment: @isherwood There is no leakage from roof or the attic. FYI I invited a couple of professionals to have a look but they scratch their head. I am looking to find out if someone else had a similar case and any advice or opinion is appreciated. Would you say that the dampness comes from the walls rather than the ground?

Comment: @Huesmann Yes to your first question. The left floor type is a vinyl sheet. It's the kitchen there and according to a moisture reading that place is dry.

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, my first time on this forum. It's a two floor terraced house. And this happened on the ground floor.

Comment: @isherwoord I added more context from the commentary on the question paragraph, I hope this makes it easier.

Comment: Wet stains only come from a very few places.  If no roof/floor or pipe leaks, that usually only leaves animals or people.  Depending on conditions it can remain wet/damp for a week or more if the leak stops.

Comment: @crip659 Thank you this makes sense. Nonetheless, I don't have any pets and I live alone, I didn't spill anything. Allegedly, the previous owner had dogs, however, you can still feel the moisture; so it shouldn't be that, 2-3 years have past since the previous owner left.

Could I ask you if you think it's a case of rising damp? Since the house is old and it doesn't have the damp proofing course like the new builds have. I personally doubt that, you may know better.

Comment: It seems weird that the dampness is on the corners.  Do you have access above this floor, like an attic?

Comment: @Huesmann Yeah indeed. Yes the above floor has some bedrooms and its fine. The one above it is the attic (roof).